# Dúvida ao utilizar o plugin inappbrowser do cordova

Tags: apache-cordova

Estou utilizando o plugin [inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) para poder acessar de dentro do meu webapp algumas paginas que estão no meu servidor. Até ai tudo bem, funciona perfeitamente, mas estou querendo utilizar um outro plugin do cordova dentro desses arquivos que estão no servidor, o plugin "[vibration](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration)" do cordova mas não estou conseguindo pois não tenho lá o `cordova.js` e mesmo que eu leva apenas esse arquivo javascript para lá, isso não será suficiente, pois esse arquivo utiliza muitos coisas.

Alguém já passou por isso? sabe como solucionar esse dependência?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, você tem um problema bem complicado aqui. Quase nenhum plugin do Cordova é somente em JavaScript, eles possuem uma parte codificada em Java ou outras linguagens dependendo de cada plataforma além do fato de precisarem de permissões para cada ação.

Por exemplo no plugin Vibration mencionado percebemos que dentro da pasta `SRC` existe diversos códigos que devem ser adicionados ao projeto do aplicativo. Não podendo ser requsitados de um servidor.

Outro problema que pode ocorrer facilmente é a hospedagem de diferentes versões de arquivos `JS`, podendo causar problemas futuros.

Porém...

Como Cordova é uma tecnologia relativamente nova, que não possui suporte a tudo ainda é comum encontrar usuários e desenvolvedores pensando em alternativas e soluções para problemas como este.

Eu não sei como você pretende incorporar esse plugin em seu projeto e quando ele deve ser incorporado. Porém suponho que você deva querer utilizar ele em apenas um caso específico. Por exemplo requisitar o plugin somente quando for ativado as notificações ou algo similar.

Se for algo desse estilo recomendo que implemente todas as funções no seu aplicativo, mas todas as funções que você utilize e que possa utilizar, feito isso crie `events` no seu aplicativo para disparar essas funções. Dessa forma você pode fazer uma comunicação do seu servidor de Web utilizando requisões JavaScript, porém emitindo eventos. E sim, o aplicativo deve ficar com tamanho maior, porém tudo deve funcionar sem problemas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas resolvi o problema utilizando um iframe no meu html. vlw

Comment: @Anderson, aqui no Stack a gente diz "obrigado" votando positivamente as respostas ;) E publicar sua própria solução também é incentivado. Valeu!

Comment: @brasofilo, eu pensei que deveria votar positivamente apenas as respostas que fossem uteis para a solução do meu problema, por isso não votei positivamente. Deveria votar mesmo assim? E no meu comentário eu informei como resolver o problema, talvez faltou eu detalhar um pouco mais minha solução, mas mesmo assim obrigado pelas dicas. flw

Comment: @Anderson, bom, eu também voto quando vejo que houve esforço por parte da pessoa e traz alguma informação nova. Mas, com certeza, a decisão é toda sua... não quero forçar barra nenhuma. Saudações!